# Access shared storage location in Xamarin Forms iOS app

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to access the storage location of using app groups in Xamarin forms application? I have seen the reference of accessing the same from Xamarin iOS app. Refer: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/watch/working-with/app-groups/

Could not find the option in Forms app. The provision to enable app groups is not seen in Xamarain Forms application properties window.

Any help on this.

Comment: I don't think that the "App Groups" concept is applicable to Android or Windows Phone, as such I can't imagine there is a Xamarin.Forms cross-platform solution to utilize that functionality. The only app-level configuration is a change to the Entitlements.plist, I believe, which wouldn't happen in the Xamarin.Forms code.

Comment: Sharing is only needed for iOS component. Support for android and WP. Is it possible in Xam forms in that case?

Comment: What are you trying to share? Just files? The entire implementation that uses app group sharing has to be in the iOS specific project. Files and settings already require using dependency injection with a platform specific implementation, so there's no reason you can't just use the app group (as in Xamarin's examples) in your iOS specific implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Working with App Groups is platform specific to iOS, so code-wise you will need to make use of the dependancy service:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/

To enable App Groups you will need to open the `Entitlements.plist` file in your *iOS Project* rather than the shared / PCL project - again this is because it is a platform specific feature.